# Android Studio/IntelliJ keeps setting "gradleHome" to an incorrect location

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

In my Android Studio/IntelliJ projects, the file .idea/gradle.xml is automatically generated when I open my project.

For whatever reason, this file is generated like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="testRunner" value="PLATFORM" />
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../../../../ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/gradle/tools/gradle-6.8" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" />
          </set>
        </option>
        <option name="resolveModulePerSourceSet" value="false" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

What's really bugging me here is the "gradleHome" option, that is set to `$PROJECT_DIR$/../../../../../ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/gradle/tools/gradle-6.8`.

This folder doesn't even exist, so where is Android Studio/IntelliJ getting this path from?

My GRADLE_HOME env var is different.

Comment: Will it even be changed if you set it to the correct location?

Comment: What Gradle do you use for this project from command line?

Comment: It seems that changing the "gradleHome" option doesn't really do anything... ? I am trying to use gradle 7.0

Comment: What option do you have set for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM** when open these settings? If you change it to a different location - will it be preserved for this project?

Answer (score 0):

Based on IntelliJ IDEA [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html):

> If Gradle location has been defined by the environment variables
> GRADLE_HOME or PATH, then IntelliJ IDEA deduces this location, and
> suggests this path as the default value.

If you are sure GRADLE_HOME is not set like the value in the gradle.xml file you should also your [PATH variable](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/). I am not sure about the precedence, which variable is taken first if both are present.

It looks like you installed Gradle globally with the chocolatey software manager. And maybe this software sets the PATH during the installation.

Probably you removed Gradle installation already, but this value is still in the PATH.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the env vars, and there really isn't anything there that should lead AS/IntelliJ to that path. I even restarted my computer, removed the .idea and .gradle folders in the project and re-opened (imported) the project. And again the path is to 6.8.